# Count visitor using session but not update until browser is closed

Tags: php, session

I want to show visit counter that doesn't get updated until I click on another browser tab or close the page. When I reopen the browser it gets updated.

Please send me a visit counter like that.

I tried it but it didn't work properly.

Comment: Could you show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

i understand your problem..
first of all, make two text files

- **ip.txt** (ip Address of client will be stored in this file)
- **counter.txt** (number of visitors with different ip address will be stored in this file)

now, make a **counter.php** file like,
**counter.php**

```
<?php


$filename = "counter.txt";
$ip_filename = "ip.txt";

function inc_count()
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    global $filename, $ip_filename;

    if(!in_array($ip, file($ip_filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)))
    {
        $current_value = (file_exists($filename)) ? file_get_contents($filename): 0 ;
        file_put_contents($ip_filename, $ip . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

        file_put_contents($filename, ++$current_value);
    }
}

inc_count();
?>
```

now, run this **counter.php** and after that check both **ip.txt** and **counter.txt**.

Sure..it will help you..!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go ahead with JQ then try [live Counter using jQuery & CSS](http://w3lessons.info/2014/01/12/live-counter-using-jquery-css/).

You can also try [AJAX with JQ](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/310527-using-ajax-to-retrieve-a-counter-variable-from-server-and-update/) and [simple Ajax with PHP click tracker](http://mistonline.in/wp/simple-ajax-with-php-click-tracker/).